# Using NVD3 chart in Leaflet control

Tags: javascript, html, charts, leaflet, nvd3.js

I followed the Leaflet choropleth map  [tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/) and want now include a NVD3 chart into the control on the top-right corner. If I am making an extra `<div>` besides the map and include `<svg>` everything works fine. I am creating the info control like that:

```
var info = L.control();

info.onAdd = function(map) {
  this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info', ); // create a div with a class "info" 
  this.update();
  return this._div;
};
```

I fill it with content like that:

```
info.update = function(props) {
  this._div.innerHTML = (props ?
    '<h4>' + props.Name + '</h4>' + props.number :
    'Click on an area');
};
```

I tried to include here the same `<div>` that works when I put it next to the map `<div>`:

```
<div><svg/></div>
```

But nothing appears. That's my graph:

```
function exampleData() {
  return [{
      "label": "One",
      "value": 29.765957771107
    },
    {
      "label": "Two",
      "value": 0
    },
    {
      "label": "Three",
      "value": 32.807804682612
    },
    {
      "label": "Four",
      "value": 196.45946739256
    },
    {
      "label": "Five",
      "value": 0.19434030906893
    },
    {
      "label": "Six",
      "value": 98.079782601442
    },
    {
      "label": "Seven",
      "value": 13.925743130903
    },
    {
      "label": "Eight",
      "value": 5.1387322875705
    }
  ];
}

nv.addGraph(function() {
  var chart = nv.models.pieChart()
    .x(function(d) {
      return d.label
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return d.value
    })
    .showLabels(true);

  d3.select("#chart svg")
    .datum(exampleData())
    .transition().duration(350)
    .call(chart);

  return chart;
});
```

I think it has something to do with `L.DomUtil.create` since here the `<div>` for the control panel is created. But I did not manage to tell NVD3  to render the plot within the control panel. Do you have an idea?
One strange thing happens too:
I see and empty area below the text in the control panel (where the graph should have be rendered). And if I click on my features the text changes as intended, but also the empty field below increases with every click. This just happens if I include the `<div>` containing `<svg/>` in `info.update`.

Comment: Could you put your code up on a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) so its easy to have a look at what you have done so far. And its easier to help.

Comment: Here's a working example: [Combine Leaflet + NVD3](https://jsfiddle.net/andieich/dpvwjo6q/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not complicated it sounds. You'll probably have a laugh once you read my solution.

At the point you create the pieChart `nv.addGraph(function() {..}` in the line that you select the element to render the chart `d3.select("#chart svg")` **the browser is assuming the DOM element exists**, which is not the case.

You were right in assuming that it had to do something with `L.DomUtil.create`. This is the point where you call `this.update();` to actually render the `<div id="chart"> <svg/></div>` required for your NVD3 pieChart.

So here is what I did to your code.

```
function createPieChart() {
  nv.addGraph(function() {
    var chart = nv.models.pieChart()
    ...  
    ...
    return chart;
  });
}
```

Wrapped it in a `createPieChart()` function so it could be accessed when 
required.

And inside your `info.update()` I'm calling the `createPieChart()` function once the innerHTML has been created.

```
// method that we will use to update the control based on feature properties passed
info.update = function(props) {
  this._div.innerHTML = (...); //WHICH DIV HAS TO BE GENERATED

  // Now we can create the Pie Chart  
  createPieChart();
};
```

And now it works as expected.

You can find a working [version here](https://jsfiddle.net/shabeer90/9rctto77/)

Hope it helps

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot for that! Makes sense now. I'm still very new to all this. One other thing: Do you have any clue why the info control is growing every time you click on a feature?

Comment: Figured it out myself, I only defined height within the `<svg/>`, if I additionally define width it works.